# Convert RAID 1 to RAID 10 in mdadm

Tags: software-raid, mdadm

In my current Ubuntu server, I have 2x 2TB Western Digital RED hard drives in a RAID 1, using mdadm. I would like to add 2 more 2TB RED drives, and convert it to a RAID 10. I realize I would have to wipe the data most likely, but is there any way that I wouldn't need to? I have the 2TB volume almost completely filled up

Comment: I believe the level option of mdadm --grow will allow this. I have used it to go from raid5 to raid6 but not from raid1 to raid10 so I have not tested that.

Comment: BTW before you would grow you would add the 2 other drives as spares.

Comment: Similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/43677/best-way-to-grow-linux-software-raid-1-to-raid-10

Comment: @KevinPanko Exact duplicate! Oh well, he got my upvote

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This took some strategy, and unfortunately, was a little while ago, so bear with me; I'm going by memory.

Essentially, I shut down the server, and installed the two new drives. I did a backup beforehand to an External 4TB HDD (much faster since it had USB3!), just in case. I didn't need to use it thankfully, but I'm happy I at least had it. I took note of what the partition sizes were on the disk (by block size), and what each disk was. At the time, `sda` and `sdb` were the drives with the current array loaded. `sdc` and `sdd` were the new drives. I copied the partition layout to the two new disks, using `fdisk` as root. I then created a new array, with two missing members:

```
mdadm -v --create /dev/md1 --level=raid10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdc1 missing /dev/sdd2 missing
```

This command creates the array, called `/dev/md1`, sets the RAID type to 10, and says that there should be 4 devices, in a perfect world. The devices I added were `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdd1` for the first partition. Once it was up, I mounted the array (as `/mnt/raid`), and did an `rsync -avP /mnt/data/ /mnt/raid/`, and waited a day for everything to copy.

Once it was copied over, you need to fail the hard drives in the array, and remove them: `mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1 --remove /dev/sda1`. You can then add that hard drive to the new array, and wait for it to rebuild. Then, remove the last drive from the array (using `/deb/sdb` instead), and add it back (`mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sda1`).

Finally, to remove the old array from starting up or giving warnings, run `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`. At this point, the old array is gone! I would suggest double-checking that the boot loader is installed correctly on the array (or, depending on your scheme, the boot sector of the hard drives). Give it a test reboot; if everything comes up, great! If not, that's why we have a backup!

As a bonus, I learned a new useful command: `watch cat /proc/mdstat` to automatically update the screen every 2 seconds with the rebuilding status of your drives. I also [wrote a blog entry](https://www.talk-about-it.ca/growing-2-disk-raid1-array-to-4-disk-raid10-array/) about my experience, including pictures.

Comment: [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/a/43712/257516) has a very similar procedure, with one notable suggestion: try to boot your new array before destroying the old one (it's okay to fail *one* of the drives in the old array beforehand, but not both).

Comment: @Jonathan already posted as a comment to the question

Comment: Oh, right. Although, I believe it bears mentioning that specific difference explicitly.

Comment: Simulated this with loopback devices using `/dev/loop0`, `/dev/loop1`, `/dev/loop2`, `/dev/loop3` , with each pointing to files `disk0.img`, `disk1.img`, `disk2.img`, `disk3.img` . It worked and I managed to write it fully with text file and managed to read it back without any corruption. One thing I couldn't figure out, with `mdadm --details /dev/mdX`, `Used Dev Size` was half of `Array Size`, I repeated it while changing order of `missing`, it didn't matter. I  have 3 other RAID arrays, 2 of them RAID 1, one of them RAID10 with 2 disks using `f2` layout,for all both sizes equal.Any guesses?

Comment: @CanadianLuke When you `mdadm --detail /dev/mdX` , what is `Array Size`  and what is `Used Dev Size` ?

Comment: @sdkks not sure, that was a few years ago

Comment: @CanadianLuke Oops, I was hoping you would still have the same array :) Thanks. Couldn't find anything about it on Google yet

Comment: Let me pop on a computer. Join the chat room "root access"

Comment: @CanadianLukeREINSTATEMONICA my situation is as described in your blog post. Excellent blog post, thank you! The only thing that is not clear is whether I can do this on Debian 10 (/ is on ext4 RAID 1 on sda & sdb) online, i.e., not bringing the server down and booting from a live CD?

Comment: @Gaia Yes, as long as at least one of the disks stays online. However, if the system is a very busy one, it may be worthwhile (and, actually, recommended) to do it offline with a LiveCD or similar. You don't want to be pounding against both copies of your data while trying to recover

Comment: only the root partition needs to be transitioned. most of the activity is on an SSD, and there is only one guest VM using the same HD (but on a different partition) as the root partition. Should be good. You are a savior thank you - there is no way I could bring this system offline :) Same instructions still apply for keeping the system online?

Comment: @Gaia Make sure you have good working backups first! Last thing I want is someone blaming me if they mistype a command and break something they didn't mean to

Comment: thx, I have daily triple backups (local, usb drive, cloud)

Comment: @CanadianLukeREINSTATEMONICA sent you a message on Keybase.

Answer (score -1):

If the RAID controller supports restructuring RAID 1 -> RAID 10, yes, possible loss of data.

Software RAID ...

Add the empty net RAID 1 on two new HDD. Will Raid c similar reliability and without the risk of losing data.

Comment: Uhhh... What? *15 character minimum*

Comment: @Luke Software RAID to me about it ... http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=THJDDF8XDKQ#t=285s