# mdadm grow from RAID1 to RAID10

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I've seen [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/610538/convert-raid-1-to-raid-10-in-mdadm) about how to convert from RAID1 to RAID10, but reading the mdadm manpage seems to me recent mdadm allows for reshape from RAID1 to RAID10 by going through a reshape from RAID1 to RAID0 first, and then from RAID0 to RAID10, so I gave it a try.

/dev/md1 is my RAID1 being reshaped to RAID10. It uses /dev/sdc2 and /dev/sdd2. Here are the commands I've issued so far (moslty by trial and error, I don't really have important data on that array by now):

```
1 mdadm -G /dev/md1 -l 0 
2 mdadm -G /dev/md1 -l 10 -n 4 --add /dev/sdd2 
3 mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sda2
4 mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sdb2
5 mdadm -G /dev/md1 -n 4
```

After command 4, /proc/mdstat was showing a resync in progress and 2 spare drives. After command 5, it started to show a reshape in progress, but the reshape is stuck at 0% and the numbers never move:

```
md1 : active raid10 sdb2[4] sda2[3] sdd2[2] sdc2[0]
      976435008 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/3] [U_UU]
      [>....................]  reshape =  0.0% (65408/976435008) finish=581030.1min 
speed=28K/sec
```

How can I make mdadm resume the reshape operation?

EDIT:

The system was deadlocked. I finally rebooted it but grub doesn't find the array. Now I've booted it with sysrescuecd, but mdadm can't start the array:

```
root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --assemble --scan                      
mdadm: /dev/md/fx:1 exists - ignoring
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdd2 to /dev/md125: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdb2 to /dev/md125: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sda2 to /dev/md125: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdc2 to /dev/md125: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md125: Invalid argument
mdadm: /dev/md125 assembled from 0 drives - not enough to start the array.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

and dmesg says, for all devices:

```
[ 1001.430107] md: sda1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
[ 1001.430137] md: md_import_device returned -22
[ 1001.430214] md: md125 stopped.
```

I've also tried:

```
root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --assemble --metadata=0.90 /dev/md1 /dev/sdd2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd2
mdadm: /dev/sdd2 has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

Is there anything else I can try to rebuild the array?

Comment: How long did you wait for the reshape (although it never moved from 0.0%)...? sometimes a reshape/resync can take some time.... how big are  your drives?

Comment: I suspect the system is deadlocked. Now many other commands just hang and I need to open a new session to enter more commands. Even the login from ssh hangs before giving me the shell prompt.

Comment: did you solve this issue?. I currently have a RAID1 with two 1TB disks, and in the future I would like to upgrade to four 1TB disks with RAID10